# Pick UIDocument automatically in UIDocumentBrowserVC

Tags: ios, swift, uidocument, uidocumentbrowservc

I am using a `uidocumentbrowservc` and want to pick a `UIDocument` programmatically. In my case it is because i want to automatically load the last used `UIDocument` to save the user some time on launch, as my app seldom changes documents.

My naive approach is to store last used `URL` in `UserDefaults`. Then in the `viewDidLoad()` of my  `uidocumentbrowservc` I call `presentDocument(at: URL)`. But it doesn't work. And when i call `URL.checkResourceIsReachable()` I get the error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “myFile” couldn’t
>   be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."

The file path is:

```
/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/MyApp/myFile.
```

As far as I understand, I don't have access to it because it is not in my sandbox (It could be anywhere the user saves it?).

Any suggestions? I am sure there exist better ways to do this.

Comment: please improve the formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just save the URL. You need to save the sandbox extension granted to you by UIDBVC as well. Saving a bookmark instead of the URL will do that. In addition, a bookmark will keep working if the user moves the file (e.g. renamed inside iCloud Drive on a different device). A plain URL will not.

Check out URL’s bookmarkData(options:includingResourceValuesForKeys:relativeTo:) with options .withSecurityScope and URLByResolvingBookmarkData:options:relativeToURL:bookmarkDataIsStale:error: (and then don’t forget to call start/stopAccessing on the resulting URL)

Comment: Thanks, it worked!  As a note I didn't find the .withSecurityScope option, maybe it only is available on macOS?. Also as far as I understand UIDocument takes care of start/stopAccessing.

Comment: Right, withSecurityScope is only available on macOS. I guess you actually don't need it for UIDBVC-originated items. The sandbox info seems to be persisted in a different way.